# Keyboard shortcut to unhide or unminimize a window in OS X

Tags: keyboard

I am asking this question because I feel it belongs on apple, not superuser. Also the perfect answer is not checked off there.

You hide a window using <kbd>⌘ + M</kbd>. However even <kbd>⌘ + ⇥</kbd> to that window does not help as the window is minimized. How do you unminimize?

Comment: The correct way to go about this would have been to have a mod migrate the question.

Answer (score 101):

A very quick keyboard method to un-minimize a specific window or un-minimize all of an app's minimized windows is this:

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd> to the app with minimized windows, but don't release the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key.

While still holding <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> down, tap <kbd>Down ↓</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd> (easy 1-handed access) to enter App Exposé. Once in App Exposé, all keys can be released.

To un-minimize *all* windows, select any window with arrow keys, then press <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Return ↩</kbd>.

To un-minimize a specific window, navigate to the window you want with the arrow keys, then press <kbd>Return ↩</kbd>.

Comment: Nice. Lets keep this up. Good to know all the different ways to do this.

Comment: You can also ⌘+Tab, keep holding ⌘, release tab, press option, release ⌘

Comment: The problem with this is that all the windows are un-minimized onto the current Mac Space. They don't remember which Space they were before being minimized.

Comment: This seems to not work with Chrome

Comment: Spotlight opens a minimized window in its original Space. Cmd+Spacebar, start typing the App name, enter.

Answer (score 90):

When you <kbd>⌘ + ⇥</kbd> to that application, hold the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key before releasing <kbd>⌘</kbd>. This will *reopen* the application, typically bringing up a minimized window if there are no other windows up.

An alternative is to minimize using <kbd>⌘ + H</kbd> which hides the window, but does not actually minimize it, therefore you can still <kbd>⌘ + ⇥</kbd> to it without any special action.

Comment: As a side note, I wish I could get the original answer a few hundred up votes. This is knowledge that apparently NOBODY has. People built scripts in that answer to get it working, yet there already exists a keyboard shortcut nobody is aware of.

Comment: The Option-key trick will only work if all of an app's windows are minimized, and then it will only un-minimize one of the windows.

Comment: +1 - So awesome to know. Can't believe I've just learned it today.

Comment: @Dmitriy: indeed, shortcut implementation on OSX is very inconsistent/unclear

Comment: Thanks for the cmd-H tip. Using cmd-H to get rid of a window instead using cmd-M makes it 5 times as easy to get the window back.

Comment: I keep accidentally hitting cmd-M, but it's good to know the fix for when cmd-H is accidentally used instead 