# When would you intentionally minimize a window?

Tags: shortcut, window-manager

#### Context

Several times a week, I accidentally minimize a window by mistake. This is often by hitting <kbd>⌘ M</kbd> when aiming for another keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>⌘ N</kbd> (`New Window`). Each time, I would spend 5-15 seconds being perplexed and then go about unhiding the window. Over 10+ years of using OSX, I wasted about 10 hours of my life on this little pitfall.
Today I finally learned to disable this shortcut:

- [Disable Command-M to minimize window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73886/disable-command-m-to-minimize-window)
- [How do I disable the Minimize (command-M) shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115562/how-do-i-disable-the-minimize-command-m-shortcut/125628)
- [Keyboard shortcut to unhide or unminimize a window in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26182/keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-or-unminimize-a-window-in-os-x)

#### The question

What is the `Minimize` window feature for? What is its intended use case? When/why would you intentionally use it?

My usual workflow is:

- If a window is needed later, I just leave it as is (behind another window I'm actively using) or move it to a different desktop.
- If a window is no longer needed, I just close the window.

I have never intentionally minimize a window. Maybe I have been missing out on its usefulness?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask has the details about why questions like this are considered off-topic.

Comment: No, I never Minimize windows. I've changed to the Key command to "all the meta-keys" M, which I'll never press accidentally. Minimize is an old paradigm from early GUI systems, but now we have Mission Control, Application windows, Command Tab, the Window menu, right-clicking on the Dock....

Answer (score 1):

I don’t like a cluttered workspace. I minimize windows many times a day to keep the workspace clean. A simple click on the minimized window hanging out in the Dock brings it right back to the workspace, exactly where I positioned it, with the same size and shape.

Different strokes for different folks.